# Cron job not running ssh

Tags: bash, cron

I am trying to run a cron job.

I created a cron job in crontab -e which is

```
MAILTO=artsoulxx@gmail.com
0 */1 * * * cd /home/script.sh &>/home/log/script.log
```

and saved it with nano editor

and my script.sh file contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
/root/Icecast2GoogleAnalytics/
mvn package
/root/Icecast2GoogleAnalytics/target
java -jar icecast2googleanalytics-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar /config.xml
```

but the cronjob doesn't seem to be running because no output is being generated and saved in script.log?

Comment: cron should have send an email containing all this information.

Comment: `cron` runs your command in a [restricted environment](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it). It is likely that you have to adjust your `PATH` or write down the full path of `mvn` and `java` as `/path/to/mvn` and `/other/path/to/java`.